# Cardinality of the cokernel

Tags: group-theory, modules

I'm reading this [article](http://www.numdam.org/article/RSMUP_1993__89__103_0.pdf) and I don't understand what the authors are doing in Theorem 3, part 1:
The authors wanted to compute the cardinality of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\Lambda$. They computed the relation matrix $A$ for the module $\Lambda$ (i.e. $\Lambda = coker(A)$):

$A = \begin{bmatrix} l & 0 \\ 0 & m \\ n & n \end{bmatrix}$,

with $l,m,n \ge 1$. They conclude that $\Lambda= \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{d_1\mathbb{Z}} \times \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{d_2\mathbb{Z}}$ with $d_1 = \gcd(l,m,n)$ and $d_2 = \frac{\gcd(lm,ln,mn)}{d_1}$ (and hence that the cardinality $|\Lambda|$ equals to $d_1d_2$).

I don't see where the $\gcd$ comes from and why this statement is true.

Comment: Presumably, using the Smith Normal Form, which lets you just read off the index of the corresponding subgroup, hence the cardinality of $\Lambda$.

Comment: I don't see how the Smith Normal Form gives me the answer: I know that if $A$ is an invertible matrix (and hence square) then $det(A= | \Gamma|$. In our case the matrix is rectangular.

Comment: As I said, the Smith Normal Form lets you read off the index of the subgroup that corresponds to the matrix, and the index of the subgroup is the dimension of the cokernel. Invertibility has nothing to do with it. The gcds you mention arise naturally in the Smith Normal form, and I would guess that you end up with a Smith Normal Form that looks like $\left(\begin{array}{cc}d_1&0\\0&d_2\\0&0\end{array}\right)$, from which you read off the cardinality of the corresponding cokernel.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/107652/742).

Comment: That said, doing an example didn't come out with the value described. I tried $\ell=42$, $n=70$, $m=30$, so $d_1=2$, $d_2= 210$, and what I got was $\mathbb{Z}/14\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/30\mathbb{Z}$; same size, but not the same invariant factors.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the explanation. I tried your example with the website "http://www.numbertheory.org/php/smith.php" and this is what I've found:
$A= \begin{bmatrix} 42 & 0 \\ 0 30 \\ 70 & 70 \end{bmatrix}$ then $SNF(A)= \begin{bmatrix}= 2 & 0 \\ 0  & 210 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Then I must have done something wrong when I tried to compute the Smith Normal form. From the SNF(A) you have, you can read off that the index is $2\times 210$, with invariant factors $2$ and $210$, so you get that the quotient, $\Lambda$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/210\mathbb{Z}$...

Comment: Oh, I know what I did wrong. $14\nmid 30$, so I wasn't done...